# reload div without refresh page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a select option that shows the states
and I have a DIV return the cost of shipping of the selected state
my problem is that page refreshed when I select an option and return the value of DIV
I want to display the value of DIV without refresh the whole page

```
    <html>
<body>
<div id ="content"> this is the cost of shipping of :
<?php 
    $ship=20;
    if (isset($_POST['city'])){
        $listings = $_POST['city'];
    } else if (isset($_GET['city'])) {
        $listings = $_GET['city'];
    } else {
        $listings = 'city';
    }
    switch ($listings) {
        case 'California':
            $ship=$ship+5; echo $ship;
            break;
        case 'Alabama':
            $ship=$ship+10; echo $ship;
            break;
        case 'Texas':
            $ship=$ship+15; echo $ship;
    }

?>
    </div>
    <form id = "form1" name = "form" >
        <select id ="city" name ="city" method="post"   onchange="this.form.submit()"    >
            <option value="California" <?php echo (isset($_POST['city']) && $_POST['city'] == 'California') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>California</option>
            <option value="Alabama" <?php echo (isset($_POST['city']) && $_POST['city'] == 'Alabama') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Alabama</option>             
            <option value="Texas" <?php echo (isset($_POST['city']) && $_POST['city'] == 'Texas') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Texas</option>
    
        </select>
    
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

java script

```
   <script type="text/javascript" >
$("#form1").click(function(){
    $("#content").load(" #content");
});
</script>
```

Comment: use ajax . did you tried it ? If yes what error are you getting ?

Comment: i used ajax but nothing shown from the script , please help me ..

Comment: add code which you have tried as well in your question

Comment: i adde a script and remove the Onchange from select option that i used but nothing change

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `onchange` event of jquery and get value of select then pass the same to your `php` page using ajax . Changes you need to make in your code :

Your **html** code:

```
  <!--remove onchange from here-->
  <select id ="city" name ="city">
     <!--same code -->
   </select>
```

Your **jquery** code :

```
//onchange of select
$("#city").change(function() {
  //get select value
  var city = $(this).val();
   console.log(city)
  //ajax call 
  $.ajax({
     url: 'urlofphppage',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      'city': city
    },
     success: function(data) {
      alert('Data: ' + data);
      //add data which recieve from server to div
      $("#content").html(data);
    }

  });
});
```

Your **php** page :

```
 if (isset($_POST['city'])){
        $listings = $_POST['city'];
   
    switch ($listings) {
        case 'California':
            $ship=$ship+5; 
            echo $ship;//will send back to ajax as response
            break;
        case 'Alabama':
            $ship=$ship+10;
             echo $ship; //will send back to ajax as response
            break;
        case 'Texas':
            $ship=$ship+15;
           echo $ship; //will send back to ajax as response
    }
  }
```

Comment: It will automcatically gets call when you change any options . You can test it change option in select and check your browser console you will see value of current option selected.Check [this](https://api.jquery.com/change/) for more info.

Comment: it's work by adding <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 but another select option shown

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? What do you mean by another select option shown?

Comment: the photo show what i mean      https://ibb.co/44tskk4

Comment: Yes because in your code you have 2 select box and I think `id` of both you have given same here please change id of second select box and accordingly change `$("#city")...` as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218332/discussion-between-swati-and-kemar-aim).